# Emitter follower augmented input current

Tags: math, emitter-follower

[image: Emitter follower augmented]

Hello, I have this emitter follower augmented ( I think that's his name in english)
but I don't know from where is the beta+1 on the Iin ecuation?

Comment: You're asking why \$I_{B3} = \frac{I_{E3}}{\beta+1}\$? And "Q3 is in forward active mode" is not enough explanation?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm asking.
Edit: I looked into that and it  explains why.

Comment: Your circuit is a current-mirror with beta helper not an emitter follower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q3 is in forward active mode because the base-emitter junction is forward biased and the base-collector junction is reverse biased.

In this mode we have the **very** well known characteristic 
$$I_c = \beta I_b .$$

Since the current coming out of the emitter is (by KCL) the sum of the base and collector currents,

$$I_e = I_b + I_c = I_b + \beta I_b$$

and thus

$$I_b = \frac{I_e}{1+\beta}.$$

(Note: circuit theory purists would normally take \$I_e\$ to mean the current going **in** to the emitter, so there'd be some sign changes in the equations above)